# Why do I get a "Parameter is not valid." exception when I try to save an image?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Savetool.Click
    Using bm As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image.Clone, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
        SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "Picture 1"
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Files|*.jpg;.gif;.bmp"
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            bm.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
            MsgBox("Saved")
            bm.Dispose()
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

The code works perfectly well when the image is small,  but when it gets bigger it throws an exception.

> Parameter is not valid.

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown? Could you also give an example of a scenario when this happens? For instance, how "big" image are we talking about?

Comment: the line that the exception is thrown is
            bm As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image.Clone, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height). i have written a code that zooms an image and displays it in aa picture box so when i want to save the zoomed image 
               for example when the zoomed image size is 65555×655555. it throws this exception.

Comment: Yes, asking for a 160 gigabytes image will certainly get you that exception.  The maximum bitmap size is 2 gigabytes or the amount of available contiguous address space, which ever one is less.  Not call Dispose() on the bitmap object returned by Clone() will produce such problems as well.

Comment: I'm guessing you accidentally wrote a "5" too much for the height... A 65555^2 pixels large bitmap is quite a bit too much, like Hans says. I don't understand how you can even render it without getting an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: sorry for the late reply guys. and I want to thank you for your posts. Realy appreciated the explanation.  what I am trying to do is to try to allow the user to enlarge the image how he wants it (scale) and then save it when he hits the save button. i need to know what is the  Maximum allowed width & height of bitmap

Comment: I've got a situation where I'm creating a bitmap as follows:
**bitmap=new Bitmap(img,newWidth,newHeight)**
newWidth is say 10,000 and newHeight is like 9,000;
Upon hitting this line I get an error about invalid parameter being used. It happens almost everytime.Is there a limitation to bitmap and what is it dependent upon?